# Unable to start Spray with AspectJWeaver

Tags: java, scala, jar, aspectj, spray

I am trying to set up Kamon on my Spray / Akka service but I am not getting very far unfortunately.

I use the sbt-assembly plugin to build a single jar file which I run with a simple java -jar service.jar.

I naively thought that I would be able to weave the service with java  -javaagent:aspectj-1.8.8.jar -jar service.jar but I get :

> objc[13280]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
>   and
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib.
>   One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined. Failed to find
>   Premain-Class manifest attribute in aspectj-1.8.8.jar Error occurred
>   during initialization of VM agent library failed to init: instrument

And of course, my service doesn't start. (it works just fine without aspectj.
I also tried aspectj 1.7.4 and the paths are correct.

Any help / pointer would be very appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was because I was starting the JVM with AspectJ and not AspectJWeaver... All good now !